# Python Requests - Auth Token

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python Requests 2.7.0, and I am trying to pass a authtoken for a Session. I am able to successfully connect using `session.auth(user,pass)`, but I am unfamiliar with how to pass a authtoken into a session.

I tried using headers for the session, but this did not work. Here is the general flow of what I have:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'Authorization': TOKEN})
...
```

Comment: Define *did not work*? What does the documentation of the API tell you you need to do? Usually the header format for the `Authorization` header includes a authorization type string too, not just the token. The documentation should tell you.

Comment: So I receive a error of "<Response [401]>". I have tried these variations:

'Authorization': 'TOK:' + TOKEN and 'Authorization': 'token:' + TOKEN and

Comment: You are setting headers correctly; whatever isn't working is directly related to the header. Try to get the header to work with a straight-up request first perhaps?

Comment: It's common to use this format for tokens: `Authorization: Bearer actual-token-goes-here`. Make sure you check the docs of your API to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correctly setting a header to be used for all requests sent with the session.

You are probably not setting the header *value* correctly, however. The `Authorization` header probably has to follow a specific pattern, as outlined in the documentation for the service you are contacting. It is typical that the value must start with a authentication scheme (like the [Basic and Digest authentication schemes](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), so the value would be `<scheme> <token>`.